# PropertyChangeListener validation

Tags: eclipse, propertychangelistener

i'm try to implemente a view from eclipse preference page and in some fields this method (performStringSubstitution) not work because the StringFieldEditor do the validation before and don't give a permission to label.setText(), i'll appreciate any help. `

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event)
    {

         /*Solve Eclipse variable method (${workspace_loc},${project_loc},...)*/

         String dir = Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore()
                                         .getString(event.getNewValue().toString());

         IStringVariableManager manager = VariablesPlugin.getDefault()
                                        .getStringVariableManager();  
          try {
                String solvePathUpdate = manager.performStringSubstitution(dir);
                label.setText(solvePathUpdate);
              }
                catch (CoreException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       /* Creating the method print console */

                    }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry but it really is not clear what you are saying is wrong. What is `label`? What happens and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: i created a preference page, and now i would like to use the variable from eclipse(${workspace_loc},${project_loc},...) to set the paths (label.setText()). In case of code above, every such time what happens a path update, occurs a validation before to set , and thats the problem, the validation not recognize the variable from eclipse and not allow the set path.

Comment: The validation is a guess.